# UIView animations in Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation

I am trying to execute following code.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, animations: {        
    println("animations")
}, completion: { finished in          
    println("completion")
})
```

So Here completion block is called immediately before 5 sec animation duration. Don't know what is wrong here. 
  Please let me know for proper code.

Answer (score 2):

You should add some view for animation:

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, animations: {
    someView.alpha = 0
    println("animations")
    }, completion: { finished in

        println("completion")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any animation sequence in your `animations` block, try animating your current view and check it'll work fine.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 0.5;
        print("animations")
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.view.alpha = 1.0;
            print("completion")
    })
```